# UIModalPresentationCurrentContext and autorotation

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, autorotate, uimodalpresentationstyle

I have a UINavigationController as root. And I want to present transparent modal VC on it.
I set `modalPresentationStyle` to `UIModalPresentationCurrentContext` on UINavigationController.

When I present VC it's transparent but autorotation works without animations and bottom VC wont rotate.

Looks like bug. But how I should implement right behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is not to use UIModalPresentationCurrentContext.

Comment: Then how to achieve it? I am having same issue?